# Adding New Fields via LEFT JOIN in Running ETL from SQL to MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb

I need to run an ETL to get data from a Sybase/SQL back-end into my MongoDB environment. We already have data from Sybase, but now there are a couple of additional fields we want to pull data in for. So with my familiarity being with Mongo (not so much Sybase), I'm trying to determine how I need to adjust our ETL to get this additional data.

The current SELECT statement looks like this:

```
`SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 d.*, d10.code code10, d10.id_number as Code10ID FROM diagnosis d LEFT JOIN diagnosis_icd10 d10 on d.icd10_id = d10.id_number ORDER BY d.id_number`
```

Now, within the `diagnosis_icd10` table that we're doing the LEFT JOIN on, there are now a couple of extra fields available.

So, my question is, do I need to explicitly include these additional fields here in the SELECT statement in order for them to be available in the ETL process? Or is this only the case if I want to rename the fields? What should this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to explicitly request them, as your current query only gets all columns from the diagnosis table (aliased to d via the d*).

This has nothing to do with Sybase though this is basic SQL so would be the same for most databases. You just add them to the select statement as in d10.column_name like the others.